# Correct Format to enter into a Geography data-type database cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis

I have created a Database using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and have came across a problem when entering data.

The problem is that I don't know what format to enter data into a (Location) geography cell.

I am entering the Longitude and Latitude exactly like this > 54.763226, -1.386241

But get this error:

> The changed value in this cell was not recognised as valid. .NET Framework Data Type: SqlGeography, Error message: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography'

Please can you tell me how to add data into the Geography cell correctly?

Comment: Don't link to some file. Include the actual error message in your question. **[Edit]** it, don't post stuff like that in comments - ideally as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that.  I have taken out the links and added the actual error in as text.

Comment: As the answer below suggests, you can use the `Point` method to generate a point. But *why* this should be necessary is another question that you might find interesting. The `geography` datatype can hold more than mere points. It can hold lines, areas, and pluralities of the above. Once you know that, it makes sense that the the obvious thing of "provide two floating point numbers and interpret them as lat/long" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **geography** Data Type with the correct syntax as below

**syntax:**

*Point ( Lat, Long, SRID )*

[Reference 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx)

[Reference 2](https://colinmackay.scot/2008/02/07/different-ways-to-add-point-data-in-sql-server-2008/)

=================================================================

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EarthquakeData 
( 
     EarthquakeID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     EarthquakeInformation GEOGRAPHY NOT NULL 
)
```

Inserting data:

```
insert into dbo.EarthquakeData (EarthquakeInformation )
values (geography::STGeomFromText(
        'POINT(54.763226 -1.386241)',4326))
```

Viewing inserted data:

```
select cast(EarthquakeInformation as nvarchar(max)) from dbo.EarthquakeData
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am still getting the same error, I done exactly what you said:  Point(54.763226, -1.386241,  4326), please advise what i am doing wrong

Comment: @adamSmith updated my post... please check above... Let me know about the status

Comment: Thank you very much I will be sure to try this tonight.

Comment: Thank you very much, one of your examples worked: UPDATE dbo.HairAndBeautySalon SET Location = geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326) WHERE SalonID = 1

Comment: Pls make it as answer then 